# Removing strings under a certain number of characters in R

Tags: r, string, substring

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
V1     V2
40005  George
400    John
50005  Steve
30     Sam
(...)  (...)
```

I would need to remove those rows from the dataframe in which in the first column, the number of characters is less than 5. In this example, I would need to only retain the first and third row (corresponding to George and Steve). Both V1 and V2 are strings ("chr").

Would greatly appreciate any idea on how to achieve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try a basic subset operation using `nchar()`:

```
df_out <- df[nchar(df$V1) >= 5, ]
df_out

    V1     V2
1 40005 George
3 50005  Steve
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("40005", "400", "50005", "30"),
                 V2=c("George", "John", "Steve", "Sam"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tim Biegeleisen! This however deletes all rows in my dataframe. What is strange is that your code works perfectly when applied to df$V2, but when applied to df$V1, it seems to delete all my rows.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  My code leaves your original data frame `df` untouched, and instead generates a new data frame `df_out` with the rows you want to retain.

Comment: My bad. So sorry. Simply forgot to capitalise the "v" in "V1". Code works perfectly. Sorry to have wasted your time, and thank you so much for your help!